# Xcode 14.3.1: The device “X iPhone” is not available because it is not executable

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to use my personal iPhone to debug an app but Xcode is not accepting my iPhone. I already used it before so I enabled the Developer mode successfully and it was working. Currently, Xcode successfully gathers my iPhone's data for development but after that process an error occurs saying: "The device “Ricardo iPhone” is not available because it is not executable. Please ensure that the device is attached and that it is ready to be connected to Xcode."

My iPhone is using iOS 16.6 and the Xcode is v14.3.1. The iOS 16.4 SDK provides support to develop apps for iPhone running iOS 16.6 and the SDK comes bundled with Xcode 14.3. I really don't known how to solve the issue. I already restarted my MacBook, restarted Xcode, restarted my iPhone, re-enabled the Developer mode, I unpaired my iPhone with Xcode and re-paired it, changed USB cable. Nothing worked.

[image: Devices and Simulators in Xcode]

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple developer membership?

Comment: @matt Yes I have.

Comment: It's weird because I don't understand how a _device_ can be "executable". And of course everyone _else_ with Xcode 14.3.1 and iOS 16.6 on a device can do this just fine. You've tried everything I would have tried.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found what was missing and I'm a little embarrassed.
I changed the "Show run destination" to "Always" and things started working. That's it. So simple but hard to understand based on the message.

[image: Xcode Devices and Simulators configuration "Show run destination"]